# htaccess for subdomain help

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Usually I just use the online tools for url mod_rewrite rules but this just wouldn't work.

```
Dynamic url: http://sub.domain.com/index.php?page=index&name=test
Rewritten url: http://sub.domain.com/test OR http://sub.domain.com/test/
My htaccess:
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=index&name=$1 [L]
```

Instead of passing "test" for the variable name, I always get the value "index.php"

Anyone gurus has have any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=index&name=$1 [L]`

Might be more what you're looking for.

Also, you can pre-condition the url for trailing slashes using something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !(.*)/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=index&name=$1 [L]
```